# How to sense the presence of AC voltage that could vary from 17 V to 230 V?

Tags: voltage, ac, opto-isolator, trigger, sensing

I have a requirement to sense the presence of AC voltage, that could vary from 17 V to 230 V, and trigger a TLPxxx series optocoupler.

The wide voltage range poses a problem in the choice of a suitable resistor for the optocoupler.

Is there any other way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Some constant current circuit should be built.

Comment: Do you have any DC voltage rail available?

Comment: Use an over / under voltage relay, available off-the-shelf. https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1854397.pdf

Comment: @vu2nan Can one of those relays tolerate 230 V when it's set to 17 V? The only one that allows setting to 17 V is the 24 V model, and I feel like anything designed for 24 V operation is not going to survive 230 V. This looks more like it's designed for overvoltages on the order of 10% higher than nominal.

Comment: @Hearth - I fully agree with you, Hearth. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: What is the frequency of the AC voltage, is it constant and low like mains eg: 50Hz or 60Hz, or is it constant and high like an RF signal, or does it vary over a wide range like audio, eg: 20Hz to 20kHz?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to limit optocoupler LED current when driven with AC is a capacitor in series, as in the usual [capacitive dropper power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply). This is not dissipative, which is good.  Unfortunately current will be proportional to input voltage, which means the capacitor has to be large enough for it to work at the lowest input voltage, but not so large as to let too much current flow at the highest input voltage.

Another way would be a depletion MOSFET like BSS126 or LND150, wired as a current source, which has the advantage of more constant current. However it has other drawbacks like inaccurate Vgs (and thus current), it is dissipative, and it's an uncommon part which implies potential issues to actually get it.

So the issue is to pick a current for the opto's LED that will work across the rather wide input voltage range (17-230V RMS).

Optocouplers still work at very low LED currents, but current transfer ratio (CTR) will be lower. When the optocoupler is off, there is still dark current which increases with temperature, so the opto's LED needs to receive enough current to make a clear distinction between "off" (dark current only) and "on".

I'll pick [LTV827](https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-96-0016/LTV-8X7%20series%20%20Rev.S.PDF) which has a guaranteed maximum dark current of 100nA at 25°C. Unfortunately the datasheet doesn't spec maximum dark current depending on temperature, only typical, but according to figure 9 it goes 10x per each 25°C increase. So with a maximum ambient temperature of 75°C (to be safe) that would be 10µA.

Let's go with a minimum output current of 100µA for the phototransistor. Minimum CTR occurs at high temperatures and low LED current. Start with CTR=0.5 (unbinned optocoupler), downgrade to CTR=0.3 at high temperature (Fig 7), downgrade again to CTR=0.15 at 2mA LED current (Fig.5). Below that it falls so fast that it doesn't really feel safe. Let's go with a minimum LED current of 2mA and a minimum output current of 300µA.

That corresponds to a 16k pullup, let's go with 33k.

[image]

I adjusted CTR in the opto's model. So that should work, but to get the minimum current at 17VRMS, current limiting cap C3 has to be quite large which means high inrush current, high cost, and up to 1W dissipation in the inrush current limiting resistor R10.

Using a depletion MOSFET as current source removes current variation with input voltage. In addition, halfwave rectification halves dissipation. So we have a much better total dissipation of  about 160mW, the circuit would also work with a DC input, and there is no large expensive film cap.

However the threshold voltage of depletion MOSFETs is not accurate, so the value of R10 (and associated max/min dissipation) needs to be examined with care.

[image]

It may be easier to use a high voltage BJT wired as current source, for more accurate current.

[image]

Here's a "luxury" version:

[image]

It uses a depletion FET as current limiter, set to about 100µA, which charges C2. The two transistors make a hysteresis comparator and pulse the opto's LED at quite high current (>10mA). At the output we get ~100µs pulses which are ideal for a micro's Pin Change Interrupt to process. It uses no bulky film caps, also works on DC input, and worst case dissipation is less than 20mW with 230VAC input.

**Last one**

[image]

Using a very low value capacitor dropper lets only a tiny current through the opto. Its output current manifests as a voltage across R29. C5 integrates this current into a voltage that drives current source Q3 which then zeroes out the opto's average output current (thus compensating for dark current). Since we already have an output voltage (on node outa1) and a smoothed version of it (on node outa) we can use a LM339 comparator to detect variations. If the output of the comparator looks like a 50Hz square wave, then 50Hz AC is present on the input.

**Potential problem**

One drawback of these circuits is they may be too sensitive: if long wires are present on the input but not connected to any voltage, capacitive coupling from nearby wires may be enough to detect AC on the input. I guess this would be difficult to eliminate, because if the input has to detect 17VAC without consuming large amounts of power when it receives 230VAC, then it has to be quite sensitive... Of course the usual way to solve this problem would be to put a resistor across the input, which defeats the idea of trying not to waste too much power.

So it turns out the last circuit... was't the last one...

[image]

This one draws very low current from the input, but due to D3 the current only goes one way. So if capacitive coupling from a nearby wire occurs, well, capacitors don't conduct DC and this draws DC input current, so the output pulses once, then it stops. This can be cleaned up in software. Note C6 is our parasitic coupling cap.

[image]

Another advantage of the depletion MOSFET current source is that current (and therefore output pulses) are in phase with voltage. So by looking at the phase of the received signal, the micro can check if it's real AC (even know which phase if you have more than one)... or if it's 90° phase shifted which means it went through capacitance. This is not possible with the capacitive dropper because there's already a cap, so it's always 90° phase shifted.

Answer (score 4):

I would be inclined to use a circuit something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVlOoz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The key is a depletion mode N-channel MOSFET, which has a negative V<sub>GS(th)</sub> meaning it can be self-biased with merely a resistor, and then used as a current-regulating diode.  The compliance range of the resulting CCS is very wide, from a couple volts up to V<sub>DS(max)</sub>.  [BSP135](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSP135-DS-v01_33-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30433c1a8752013c1fd4c839399b) is a fine candidate, and there are many other suitable options.

Using a SOT-223 package, the MOSFET should be able to handle say 0.5W pretty easily, hence at a maximum of say 300V average, it should pass less than 1.5mA.  (R2 should be chosen to suit the V<sub>GS(th)</sub> grade mark on the part.)  There are SOT-23s available as well (for which a somewhat lower current setting should probably be chosen), and DPAK, TO-220, etc.

Many variations are possible, and this is just one example embodiment.  The full-wave rectifier might be skipped in favor of a single diode (half-wave), or a bidirectional current limiter (using two DMOS anti-series), with anti-parallel diode across D6 to protect it; alternately an AC type (antiparallel LEDs) opto could be used.

Note the MOV, represented as a TVS due to limitations of the CircuitLab schematic used here.  This is chosen to protect M1, in combination with R1, under mains transient conditions.  Since R1 can be fairly large (100Ω is just an example value; it should be a pulse-rated fusible wirewound or metal-oxide type at this value), the surge current and power absorbed by MOV1 can be made quite small; an even smaller MOV could be used (than the 7mm disc specified; SMT chips are available), while still offering adequately long, or even unlimited, lifetime.

R1, acting as a resistor divider with R3, can also be adjusted to give the low-voltage dead band, instead of using D7 for the purpose.

Filtering may also be desirable, for which a few nF in parallel with the rectifier input or output would be a good start.  Additional capacitance could be used to reduce output ripple (if a potentially pulsating output happens to be undesirable), or provide hold-up (so that a momentary drop of input voltage isn't immediately read as a disconnection).  A bleeder resistor (across the rectifier output) would probably be desirable in that case (ensuring the capacitor discharges at a reasonable pace, rather than through diode leakages).

I would generally recommend opto forward current above a couple 100µA or so, to give an output current reliably higher than maximum "dark" current, and to account for the low CTR that phototransistor optos have at low current levels.  More than a couple mA seems unnecessary, dissipating excess power (a capacitive dropper can be used to mitigate this, but then another constant-current scheme must be used).

Comment: The depletion nmos can also be an n-channel JFET, though I mention that purely for completeness's sake as the only JFETs that would work for the asker's application would be expensive SiC JFETs.

Comment: Indeed, SiC JFETs would be the next best option; I don't think they're available in small enough ratings to justify their use, though. One of those cases of, nothing physically prohibiting it, it's just not economical to design and produce devices that small, not enough people would use them. Ah well.

Answer (score 3):

I started off by looking at what others have done, and I found a good source of ideas at the ESP website (Rod Elliott).  In particular this link:
https://sound-au.com/appnotes/an020.htm
...and figures 7 through 13 of this link:
https://sound-au.com/appnotes/an005.htm

**DISCLAIMER:**
Mains voltages can cause fire or electrocution resulting in property loss, or severe injury or death.  The circuits described herein involve mains wiring, and in some jurisdictions, it may be illegal to work on or build mains-powered equipment unless suitably qualified.  All wiring must be performed to the standards required in your country.  If you are not qualified and/or experienced with electrical mains wiring, then you must not attempt to build any of the circuits being described herein.  **Never work on mains equipment while the mains is connected!**

**Requirements & Preamble:**
The detector must detect the presence or absence of mains voltage. Mains voltage is defined as AC voltage, let's assume 50Hz sine-wave, with amplitude (RMS) varying from 17V to 220V (a ratio of almost 13-to-1).  The opto-isolator is TLPxxx series, let's assume TLP350 is typical, refer link to datasheet below.

https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TLP350_datasheet_en_20171018.pdf?did=6217&prodName=TLP350

We shall assume that no other source of power exists to drive the opto LED apart from the AC mains being detected.

Opto LED drive required: The datasheet test conditions for most parameters use LED If=5mA, and Fig 13.2.1 shows Vf=1.65V at temp=0C.  So we shall assume the LED requires If=5mA and Vf=1.65V.

Speed: this opto (TLP350) is quite fast, propagation delay=150ns (typ).  This allows us to use a pulse-train output rather than a continuous output, which reduces the average current required to drive the opto, which reduces the current required from the AC supply, which in turn reduces the power loss in the "Mains current limiter".  This will be very important due to the wide range of AC voltage amplitude: at the lowest AC voltage (17) there must be sufficient current to power the opto LED drive circuit, while at the highest AC voltage (220V) the power loss in the AC current limiter must not be excessive.

**Circuit Description & Operation**
The circuit is shown below, comprising four main parts:

1. Mains current limiter.
2. Voltage Limiter/Regulator.
3. Detector & Pulse Generator.
4. Opto Output.

[image]

Please ignore the Opto Output section, LTspice did not have the correct model for the TLP350, so we shall only be concerned with driving the LED of the opto.

**1. Mains Current Limiter.**
This is quite standard (and presented by other answers here); capacitors are used to limit the mains current without excessive power dissipation, the 470k resistors are there really just to ensure these are discharged when the circuit is disconnected from mains.

**2. Voltage Limiter/Regulator.**
This also is very standard; I was limited by the device models in LTspice, I would not recommend using the 1N750 as the zener here, however, this is adequate for our purposes.  However, D1 is critical as we will find out.

**3. Detector & Pulse Generator.**
A close-up of this circuit is posted below.
[image]

D2 and C2 create a supply rail (~5Vdc) for this section.  This voltage [VCC_5] is established when AC power is first applied and has a slow discharge (much longer than an AC mains cycle).  R1, R2 and A1 (Schmitt-trigger inverter, eg: 74HC14) form a zero-crossing detector.  When AC mains is not present the output of A1 is steady HI.  When AC mains is present, A1 output toggles momentarily HI-LO-HI at each mains zero-crossing (every 10ms for 50Hz mains).  The HI-to-LO edge is detected by the differentiator formed by C3, R5, D7 & A2; the output of A2 is a brief positive pulse (duration ~85us) at each zero crossing.  This brief pulse then drives the forward current (~5mA) into the LED of the opto.  Remaining gates A3 to A6 are shown connected in parallel with A2, this is recommended for the case where a 74C14 or 74HC14 is used as the Schmitt inverter to ensure sufficient LED current drive capability.

Note that the zero-crossing being referred to here is that of the **current** flowing in the Current Limiter section, and due to the dropper capacitors this is out-of-phase with the mains **voltage**.

D1 is necessary to prevent the parasitic capacitance of the zener from affecting the response of the detector input node formed by voltage divider R1 & R2.  The parasitic capacitances associated with the nodes of R1 & R2 should be minimised.

**In summary:**
When AC mains is:-
A. not present:  the opto output is OFF (no LED current).
B. present:  the opto output is a train of pulses, of 85us duration, repeating every 10ms for 50Hz and every 8.33ms for 60Hz.

**Performance & Design Details:**
**Output Pulse**
The simulation results below show zoomed-in detail of the key voltages and currents for one pulse for the AC mains at (a) minimum (17V) and (b) maximum (220VAC).  In each case, the LED current pulse [Det_4] width is ~85us.  The brief duration of the LED current pulse means the average current drawn from [VCC-5V] is very low.  For the circuit presented here, the LED current pulse duty cycle is about 0.85% at 50Hz (about 1% for 60Hz), so the LED current average is just 1% of 5mA = 50uA.  This load is modelled in the sim by R3 (100k).  This pulse duration can be shortened to further reduce the average current load on [VSS_5V], however, noise immunity considerations may impose constraints on how short the pulse can be.

Image below: AC Mains = 17VAC.
[image]

Image below: AC Mains = 220VAC.
[image]

Image below: Transient Response: 5 cycles AC Mains at 220V, followed by no mains, then another 5 cycles at 17VAC:
[image]

**AC Mains Current**
The simulation results below show key voltages and currents for the AC mains at (a) minimum (17V) and (b) maximum (220VAC).

Image below: AC Mains = 17VAC.  Mains current=81uA(rms)
[image]

Image below: AC Mains = 220VAC.  Mains current=1.15mA(rms)
[image]

**First Power Up at Low AC Mains**
The simulation results below show key waveforms for the case where AC mains starts from zero and steps up instantly to minimum (17V).  In this case, it takes some time for the output pulse train to start (about 280ms), due to the time taken to establish the internal supply rail [VCC_5V].

NOTE: [Det_4] is HI (5V) before T=0.35s, please ignore this, it should be LO (0V), this anomaly is an artifact of the way LTspice simulates Schmitt-triggers (threshold is absolute, not scaled with VCC).
[image]

**First Power Up at High AC Mains**
The simulation results below show key waveforms for the case where AC mains starts from zero and steps up instantly to maximum (220V).  In this case, it takes some time for the output pulse train to start (about 17ms), due to the time taken to establish the internal supply rail [VCC_5V].  Note that in-rush current is minimal, but will be dependent upon the exact point-on-wave of the turn-on instant.  Worst-case inrush can be reduced by sizing R12 & R23 correctly.

NOTE: [Det_4] is HI (5V) before T=1.5s, please ignore this, it should be LO (0V), this anomaly is an artifact of the way LTspice simulates Schmitt-triggers (threshold is absolute, not scaled with VCC).
[image]

**Tweaks & Adjustments**

1. Adjust differentiator pulse duration to minimise [VSS_5V] load current, but beware that a lower duty-cycle means the detector output may be more susceptible to noise.
2. Adjust voltage regulator clamp voltage to suit the logic gate used as the Schmitt inverter.  For example, a 74HC14 can only tolerate up to 6V, whereas a 74C14 may permit VCC up to, say, 12V, which may increase noise immunity.
3. D1 to D7 should be small-signal types with low parasitic capacitance (all are 1N4148 in the sim).
4. Adjust R1 & R2 to suit the threshold voltage of the logic gate, and the parasitic capacitance at D1 anode.  Higher total resistance will reduce current drawn from AC Mains, but may impact the response time of the detector.
5. Adjust current limiter R12 & R23 to ensure worst-case inrush current (turn on at peak of maximum AC mains) is acceptable.
6. Current Limiter (V-dropper) capacitors: start with small values to minimise AC mains current, and increased until reliable detection occurs at minimum mains voltage.  Confirm that mains current is acceptable at maximum mains voltage (ie: power dissipation within all components from AC terminals to input of detector).
7. Adjust C2 value to suit VCC hold-up time required (at least several AC cycles), balanced with detection delay time for the case where AC mains switches from OFF to minimum (17V).
8. Adjust R6 to suit LED forward current requirements at worst-case (lowest) operating value for [VCC-5V].

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use a small and inexpensive (eg. 1W) isolated DC-DC converter so you have a power supply bus on the high voltage side.

You can then detect the voltage with a simple low-power circuit and drive the optoisolator with a fixed current (say 5-10mA) deemed to be optimal, regardless of the input voltage that is detected.

This would be a fairly compact and energy efficient approach.

Isolation for safety then depends on both the DC-DC converter and the opto-isolator, so both should have appropriate ratings and certifications.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit defines a narrow input voltage window where both MOSFETs are conducting. This avoids excessive power dissipation during the main part of the period. Short before and after the zero crossing V_G2 is low enough to enable the P-FET M2.

The voltage across the zener diode D1 limits the maximum source voltage of M1 and this, in combination with R4, limits the possible LED current and the peak power dissipation of M1. This will be below 200 mW during the pulse.

M1 must withstand the input voltage, while M2 can be a low voltage type.

A simple half wave rectifier diode on the input side may be used if the application does not need a pulse on both polarities.

The gate capacitance of M1 and M2 sets an upper limit of the possible resistor values of R1-R3. If the turn off of M2 is delayed, the dissipation in M1 becomes critical. So a gate capacitance below 30 pF for M2 is required.

D2 just uses the zener clamp voltage of D1 to protect the gate of M2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAjgzq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>