# Isolated digital input for large variable input voltage (12-240)

Tags: simulation, bridge-rectifier, digital-input

In industrial applications, relays are used to send the signal to other parts and machinery. They switch 24 DC and 220 AC on, off signal.

Although there are plenty of circuits to read input signals, I couldn't find the circuit that can operate with large variable input voltage (12-240), so I made the following circuit to detect the voltage presence.

In AC mode, power resistors and capacitors put more resistance on the current, then is fed to the bridge rectifier and then the optocoupler.

In DC mode, the capacitor does nothing and the rectifier just passes the voltage.

I might add the Zener diode and resistor for optocoupler protection

However, my calculation about the voltage divider and voltage drop by parts does not comply with the simulation result.

Appreciate it if someone corrected me about this design and simulation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use punctuation and capital letters in the right places in both title and post. Your post is difficult to read.

Comment: 240VAC, mostly across 634Ω? So  90W dissipation in the resistor and 10x the absolute maximum LED current into the 4N35.  The smoke detector may work to detect the presence of 240VAC with this circuit, but I think you need to go back to the drawing board for a practical design. 33mA is on the high side even at 24V for a reliable design.

Comment: Similar question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/687643/how-to-sense-the-presence-of-ac-voltage-that-could-vary-from-17-v-to-230-v (but not duplicate since OP also wants DC).

Comment: @Hamid Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: @VoltageSpike the simulation result is far from my calculation, I was wondering which part is incorrectly designed

Comment: @VoltageSpike Spehro Pefhany believes this circuit and logic are not working at all, while I'm getting some results from the simulation

Comment: @bobflux can I have your Idea